# Oracle SQL statement to update column value based on a matching condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I set a column value to one of 3 values based on a specific condition?

For example, I have a table called Customer with an attribute called customer_level, where this customer can have one of 3 possible levels.

Each customer will have an attribute called customer_spent, which will show how much the customer has spent.

I have a condition where if a Customer spends >= 100, they are given the S rank. If a Customer spends >= 50 but < 100, they are given the A rank. If a Customer spends >= 0 but < 50, they are given the B rank.

So, how would I make it so when one of the conditions is matched, the customer_level will be set to either S, A or B?

I am currently trying to write this in the form of an UPDATE statement for the Customer table but am unsure of how to structure the statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Typically this would not be a column in a table. You'd create a view that calculates the rank based on the total spending of the customer. That view always has the correct data and there is no code needed to verify if a customer rank needs to be be updated after each order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle there is a CASE/WHEN expression:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN spent >= 100
     THEN 'S'
     WHEN spent >= 50 AND spent < 100
     THEN 'A'
     WHEN spent > 0 AND spent < 50
     THEN 'B'
     ELSE 'NONE'
 END as rank from table;
```

Comment: Right; only, it is CASE **expression**, not function.